assign a ref to a prop passed JSX.Element
I pass a JSX element to a function as a prop(in typescript), and to make a re-usable wrapper, I wish to do some repeatable calculation inside the renderit function:
function renderit({component: JSX.element}) {
 // need to do some calculation using dom node here
return <>{component}</>
}

renderit(<div>someobject</div>)

However, in react, to do this, I need a ref(useRef) to be assigned to the component. How do I assign a ref to the component inside the renderit function?
